# JApplet does not draw circle with paintComponent(Graphics g) method

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent, japplet

Question's all in the title :). I don't know what's wrong with my code and why it won't draw the circle onto the Japplet. Can u help me?

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Event;

public class BouncingBall extends JApplet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    boolean b = true;
    long speed = 50;
    int pos = 250;

    public void init(){
        setSize(500,500);
    }
    public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y)
    {


        if(y>250)
        {
            speed = speed - 10;
        }
        else
        {
            speed = speed + 10;
        }

        repaint();
        return true;
    }
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawOval(250,pos,100,100);
        if(speed <= 20)
        {
            speed++;
            repaint();
        }
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(speed);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        if(pos>=400)
        {
            b = false;
        }
        if(pos<=100)
        {
            b = true;
        }
        if(b==true)
        {
            pos = pos +5;
        }
        else
        {
            pos = pos -5;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Imulsion

Comment: Add @Override notation for the first clue.

Comment: `public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y)`  OMG where did you get this code from?  Somewhere in last millennium?  -> [ref.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#mouseDown%28java.awt.Event,%20int,%20int%29) **Deprecated.** *As of JDK version **1.1,** replaced by processMouseEvent(MouseEvent).*

Comment: Don't call repaint in the paint method, you'll end up in running you CPU to 100%

Comment: Use timers, don't halt the EDT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I prepare my response, please have a read through

- [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)
- [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- [Painting in Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html)
- [Writing Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)
- [The Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [Thread and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html)

Okay. About the only thing you did right, was extend from `JApplet`

Your "paint" method is a complete mess...

```
public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
   // Where's the super call???  All paint methods have a super
   // if you don't call it, expect really bad things to happen...
   if(speed <= 20)
    {
        speed++;
        // Don't do this
        repaint();
    }
    try
    {
        // NEVER, EVER do this, EVER
        Thread.sleep(speed);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}

    // These choices should be made else where.
    if(pos>=400)
    {
        b = false;
    }
    if(pos<=100)
    {
        b = true;
    }
    if(b==true)
    {
        pos = pos +5;
    }
    else
    {
        pos = pos -5;
    }
    // NEVER DO THIS IN A PAINT METHOD...
    repaint();
```

As has already been pointed out, don't use `mouseDown` method, use a [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) instead

As has already been pointed out, don't paint on to the top level containers (`JApplet` or any type of window or frame), use a custom component instead.

```
public class BouncingBall extends JApplet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void init() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new BouncyPane());
    }

    protected class BouncyPane extends JPanel {

        private boolean b = true;
        private int speed = 50;
        private int pos = 250;
        private Timer timer;
        private int amount = 10;

        public BouncyPane() {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                    if (speed > 250) {
                        amount = -10;
                    } else if (speed <= 0) {
                        amount = 10;
                    }

                    speed += amount;
                    timer.stop();
                    timer.setDelay(speed);
                    timer.restart();

                    repaint();
                }
            });

            timer = new Timer(speed, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (pos >= 400) {
                        b = false;
                    }
                    if (pos <= 100) {
                        b = true;
                    }
                    if (b == true) {
                        pos = pos + 5;
                    } else {
                        pos = pos - 5;
                    }

                    repaint();

                }
            });

            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawOval(250, pos, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Please, make an effort to read through all the above links, they will highlight the problem areas in you code

Comment: Thanx so much :) I write JFrames a lot, but first time i wrote a japplet. One thing - If u implement mouselistener, u have to include all of those inherited abstract methods :)

Comment: No, not if you're not using them (in my case I used a `MouseAdapter` which provides empty implementations of all the methods from the `MosueListener` interface. That way you can choice to ignore the ones you don't want to use ;))

Answer (score 3):

The method is called [`paintComponents`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#paintComponents%28java.awt.Graphics%29) instead of `paintComponent`. It's plural. To discover such errors I recommend to you to add the annotation `@Override` to methods you, well, override.
Here it would be

```
@Override
public void paintComponents(Graphics g)
```

The compiler then will give you an error if there is no method to override.

Comment: @imulsion Does it work if you override `void paint(Graphics g)` instead of `paintComponents`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't paint to a top-level container!

Instead, add a `JPanel` (or `JComponent`) and override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method as done in the applet.  If it were being done directly in the applet, the method to override would be `paint(Graphics)`.